# How can I add variable to CountDownTimer in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use variable into the CountDownTimer constructor but the application doesn't work. Normally works with duration without a variable(like 10000). How Can I use a variable?

my code

```
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
        txt_count.setText(String.valueOf(l / 1000));
        progressBar.setProgress((int) l/ 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
            iscountering = false;
            if(temp_question.getQuestions().size() !=(temp_position+1))
                Do_Next_Question(temp_position,temp_question);
            else
                Toast.makeText(ObserverRoomActivity.this, "پایان آزمون", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
};

    private void StartTimer(){
        if(!iscountering){
            iscountering = true;
            countDownTimer.start();
        }else{
            iscountering = false;
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to use onTick(Long millisUntilFinished) method's param millisUntilFinished/1000. reffer document : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer

Comment: Seems like countDownTimer is an instance variable and you are trying to pass "duration" parameter which is not initialized yet. Need to create constructor inside the function, where you have access to "duration" parameter.

Comment: @saurabh1489 I set the value to duration before call StartTimer method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use timer like this:

```
   private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

        private void createTimer(int duration) {
            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {
                    txt_count.setText(String.valueOf(l / 1000));
                    progressBar.setProgress((int) l/ 1000);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    iscountering = false;
                    if(temp_question.getQuestions().size() !=(temp_position+1))
                        Do_Next_Question(temp_position,temp_question);
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(ObserverRoomActivity.this, "پایان آزمون", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            };
        }

        private void StartTimer(){
            if(!iscountering){
                iscountering = true;
                countDownTimer.start();
            } else {
                iscountering = false;
                countDownTimer.cancel();
            }
        }

        // Call this method to pass your duration for the timer
        private void createAndStartTimer(int duration) {
            createTimer(duration);
            startTimer();
        }
```